# Using windows winapp_driver properties in karate framework

Tags: karate

we are having a windows based legacy framework built on selenium and we are trying to embed karata framework to it. we would like to learn more on the `driver` properties and also help in how we can integrate. 
we were refering to : https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/windows also wanted to understand how 'mock' environment definition and how these two files are taking (feature file and the java class file)

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need the Java part if you use the ZIP release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

The Java part is explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#junit-4

Comment: thanks for the reply. where can i find more properties of the `driver` . a reference to a documentation please.

Comment: @SumanthMylar here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#driver-configuration

Comment: driver properties like the .click .text and also the keywords like match and others


```Feature:

  Background:
    * def session = { desiredCapabilities: { app: 'Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App' } }

    Scenario:
      Given driver { type: 'winappdriver', webDriverSession: '#(session)' }
      And driver.click('One')
      And driver.click('Plus')
      And driver.click('Seven')
      When driver.click('Equals')
      Then match driver.text('@CalculatorResults') contains '8'
```

Comment: @SumanthMylar can't understand what you are saying, ask a new question if needed. keep in mind that we are focusing on browser automation right now, unless we get contributions (maybe you or your friends can help)